# Is it possible to tell filter2D to assume pixels outside of the image have a given value?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV's [filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) (in Python), and of course because my kernel is larger than 1x1, it will sometimes go "outside" of the image. So I assume under the hood, OpenCV uses some extrapolation method to assign values to these "virtual pixels" outside of the image. The results I'm getting are consistent with it assuming a value of 0. I would like to tell it to assume a value of 255. Can I do this?

The docs mention an argument called `borderType` which sets the "pixel extrapolation method". This sounds like what I need, but the (linked) documentation is simply insufficient for me to figure out how to use this to get what I want. The docs for the `BorderType` enum just say that `BORDER_CONSTANT` assumes a value of `i` "with some specified `i`", but no clue as to how to specify it.

Comment: I don't see a way to pass in a border value to `filter2d()`. Perhaps [`copyMakeBorder()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36) will help?

Comment: Just pad your image with whatever value you want. Do your filtering. Then crop the image back to its original dimensions.

Comment: In fact, `i` is zero. IMO, BORDER_REPLICATE is always better.

Comment: have you tried putting a value for `BORDER_CONSTANT` ie `cv.filter2D(src, ddepth, kernel, BORDER_CONSTANT, i)` where `i` is your value?

Comment: filter2d has a borderType argument. If you set it to BORDER_CONSTANT, I would assume you could add the borderValue= (or possibly value=) as well. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04

Comment: that function has no signature that would take a "borderValue". copyMakeBorder is required.